# raise_for_status equivalent for http.client.HTTPResponse?

Tags: python, python-requests, http-error

Python's third party [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library has the convenient method [`raise_for_status`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status) to auto-raise an `HTTPError`.

What is an equivalent function for the built-in [`http.client.HTTPResponse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse)?

---

I made the below snippet up, and it seems pretty manual.  Is there a simple built-in function I can call, equivalent to `raise_for_status`?

```py
import http.client
from urllib.error import HTTPError

def raise_for_status(response: http.client.HTTPResponse) -> None:
    if response.status != 200:
        raise HTTPError(
            url=response.url,
            code=response.status,
            msg=response.reason,
            hdrs=response.headers,
            fp=response.fp,
        )
```

Comment: Well, `requests` is a "batteries included" package, while `http.client` is a do-it-yourself package.  I think what you've done there is quite reasonable, and certainly reusable.